# Pegar instância de classe filha

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança, construtor

Tenho uma classe:

```
class Children extends Database
```

Logo, `Children` é a classe filha e `Database` a classe pai, na classe pai tenho o atributo:

```
protected $object = null;
```

O valor dele deve ser a instância da classe filha, atualmente para setar esse atributo estou usando:

```
// Construtor da classe Children
public function __construct($id = null, $daddy  = null, $people = null)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->daddy = $daddy ;
    $this->people = $people;
    $this->object = $this;
}
```

Mas direto eu esqueço de colocar a linha `$this->object = $this;` no construtor, e isso afeta o funcionamento.

Se eu colocar `$this->object = $this;` no construtor da classe Database não dará certo pois ele vai armazenar a instância `Database` no atributo, e não a instância da classe `Children`.

Há como no construtor da classe pai eu setar esse atributo valendo o seu filho?

Para quando eu der um `new Children()` o atributo `object` da classe `Database` Já valer essa instância, tirando a necessidade de ter o `$this->object = $this;` no construtor da classe filha (`Children`).

Ao fazer `new Children()` o objetivo seria:

```
// Construtor da classe Database
public function __construct()
{
    $this->object = instancia criada de Children
}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi o último paragrafo, ao criar um `Children` vc quer q de alguma forma isso altere o estado de `Database`?

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso, ao criar um `Children` quero armazenar instância dele no atributo da classe `Database`. A dificuldade é indicar a classe filha no construtor de `Database`. O atributo `object` deve armazenar a instância da classe filha, que nesse caso é `Children`. Resumindo, seria fazer o mesmo que `$this->object = $this`, so que na classe pai (Database)

Comment: Nesse caso concreto, `Database` sempre tem de ter um objeto filho injetado, ou isso é opcional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não tem como, a filha sempre deve se referenciar à mãe e não o contrário. Tem que fazer na mão. O que poderia fazer é o construtor da classe mãe aceitar um parâmetro que receba a instância e armazene na variável, mas a chamada do construtor da mãe será necessário.

Fico pensando, e se a `DataBase` não tiver uma filha?

Na verdade isso faz pouco ou nenhum sentido. Nem vou entrar no mérito de uma classe que não é para ser uma `Database` estar herdando disso, pode ser só exemplo ruim. Mas um objeto ter uma propriedade cujo valor é a própria instância que a carrega é no mínimo esquisito. Não posso falar muito porque não sei do contexto geral, mas isso parece errado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É impossível ela não ter filho, caso não tenha, ficará apenas inutilizada. Vou citar resumidamente o uso, a `Children` é um model normal, com seus atributos, como `name`, e mais dois atributos obrigatórios (`primaryKey ` e `table`). A classe `Database` é responsável por armazenar métodos como `insert` e `listAll`. O atributo `object` que guarda a instância da filha apenas vai pegar os atributos como name, na hora de armazenar no banco. Fazendo isso, torna possível apenas usar `$children->insert()` para armazenar aquele objeto no banco, sem necessidade de colocar `Database::insert($children);`

Comment: Ela é abstrata?Como assim atributos obrigatórios? Se eles são obrigatórios eles deve estar na classe mãe. Todos os atributos que a classe devem acessar devem ser de seu conhecimento, devem ser declarados nela. Esse modelo parece ser bem errado.

Comment: Sim é abstrata, realmente deveriam estar na classe mae, estava pensando que os utilizadores seriam bonzinhos kk, vou move-los para a mãe, obrigado pelo aviso.. Não vejo como errado, a classe `Database` "escanea" a que lhe foi passada como objeto buscando e conhecendo seus atributos. Lógico que em outra linguagens não funcionariam.

Comment: Se você pretende mudar, então estava errado mesmo. Mas ainda não estou vendo a relação que você está vendo entre essas coisas. Talvez se eu visse funcionando eu poderia ver, mas não está com cara que isto deva ser assim mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

É possivel obter o nome da classe filha na classe pai da seguinte maneira:

`$this->classObjectChild = get_called_class();`

Comment: Se você ler a documentação desse método, vai perceber que isso não resolve o problema. Essa função retorna o nome da classe "Chamado pelo method estático" e isso nem se encaixa no problema acima.